# What is meant by demarcate transactions?

Tags: transactions

What is meant by demarcate transactions ? When we talk about distributed transactions ? Can someone please give me an example so far I only know that it use some code of pseudo code EOT BOT but I have no idea what these are ? Why we need demarcate transactions ?

Comment: What the heckfire are you talking about? Please give us some context. Is this a database question?

Comment: Well this term is used in middleware Information Systems

Answer (score 3):

In pseudo-code:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

# modify data here
# possibly taking multiple seconds, minutes, or hours
# during which other users are concurrently modifying 
# data in the system, including the same data records 
# this transaction is modifying

END TRANSACTION
```

The `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `END TRANSACTION` commands demarcate the transaction. They define what operations are "the transaction." Namely, the operations that occur between them. The `END TRANSACTION` in real code is usually going to be a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` or `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` type of statement.

You need to demarcate transactions because they might not be a single statement. So you need a way to group multiple statements together, then treat them as a single logical operation. For example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 100000 WHERE acct_id = 10231212
DELETE FROM deposits WHERE deposit_id = 32984727922121
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

If you add a deposit to an account but don't delete it from the list of incoming deposits, that's a bad, bad, **bad** error for which the recipient will thank you but the bank will not.